# Cover all walls of the bathroom with bathroom tiles?

Tags: bathroom, tile, waterproofing, ceramic-tile

I want to completely cover the bathroom walls with tiles, but a friend of mine told me that it's a bad idea because the walls "can't breath". He said to at least keep a portion of 20-30 centimeters on top uncovered, but he wasn't able to explain what would happen if I don't, he said he "just knows that's how it's done".

Are there any problems if I completely cover the bathroom walls with bathroom tiles?

Comment: People tile completely (ceiling included, in some cases) regularly. Your friend is mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

lol lol Walls don't breathe and you already have them completly covered, with drywall mud and paint. I don't think your friend is quite qualified to tell you anything when he has no idea what he's talking about. Tile all the walls all the way up if you want to.